# Logical equivalence rule: prove a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

For the tautology

"(¬Q)→(R→¬(P∧Q))"

how can I show that this is equivalent With the tautology

(Q or (¬Q))
By logical equivalence rules?
Would this be easier to do by using a truth table, de morgan Law etc?

Comment: Yes; remove $\to$ from the first formula using [Material implication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).

Comment: But please, note that if a formula $\mathcal A$ is a *tautology*, this means that it is always TRUE, i.e. $\mathcal A \equiv \top$.

Comment: Note that $(\lnot Q) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow \lnot (P \wedge Q))$ is a valid tautology in intuitionistic logic, whereas $Q \vee \lnot Q$ is not.

Comment: Sure. $~$ Assuming $\neg Q$, and then assuming $R$, will contradict that $Q$ and $P$ can both be true. $~$ Therefore we deduce $\neg Q\to(R\to \neg (Q\wedge P))$. $~$ Thus intuitionistically proving that it is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

A truth-table takes $8$ rows ... which is pretty doable.

Using logical equivalence rules is probably a bit quicker though. Start with rewriting the implications as disjunctions:

$$\neg Q \rightarrow (R \rightarrow \neg (P \land Q)) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$Q \lor (\neg R \lor \neg (P \land Q))$$

$$...$$

Answer (score 1):

As Mauro also said, try using $P \rightarrow Q \equiv \lnot P \lor Q$ along with associativity and distributivity.

$$\begin{align}
(\lnot Q) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow \lnot(P\land Q)) &\equiv Q \lor (\lnot R \lor (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)) \\
&\equiv Q \lor (\lnot Q \lor (\lnot R \lor \lnot P))\\
 &\equiv( Q \lor \lnot Q )\lor (Q \lor (\lnot R \lor \lnot P))
\end{align}$$

which is a tautology since $Q \lor \lnot Q$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

$\neg Q\to (R\to\neg(Q\wedge P))$ will be a tautology if it is held to be true for all evaluations of $P,R,$ and $Q$.   Let us look at both evaluations for $Q$.

- Assume $Q$; that $Q$ evaluates as $\top$ (true).   Then by substitution the implication is $\neg\top\to(R\to\neg(\top\wedge P))$, which is an implication whose *antecedant is false*.
- Assume $\neg Q$; that $Q$ evaluates as $\bot$ (false).   Then by substitution the implication is $\neg\bot\to(R\to\neg(\bot\wedge P))$, which is an *nested* implication whose *consequent is* an implication whose *consequent is true*.

Therefore what can we say?